# How to recreate (digitally) this image's texture?

Tags: texture

How can I recreate (digitally) the texture in the image below? I always loved old pics foundable in old magazines :))

[image]

Comment: If that's an old picture from a magazine, it's not a texture - it's a colour halftone which has been badly scanned/photographed.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Since it is a scanned halftone print, perhaps one could first conver a source image to simulated halftone (I am not sure of the exact steps rn, which is why I am not writing it as an answer) and then play with resizing it to triger similar moire effects as scanning the print would. And maybe some grainy overlay texture as a bonus...

Comment: I'm sure there's a question about reproducing halftone in Photoshop somewhere...